# Update sql Sem Reload com um click no Link

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria que nesse script a baixo ao clicarmos no link ele fizesse o update no sql sem o reload. ele foi feito para realizar atravez de um submit num  mais gostaria que fosse atravez de um link mesmo mais não concegui fazer.
como posso  fazer isso?

```
  <script type="text/javascript"  
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Link para fazer o update

```
   <a href="#" id="<?php echo $id?>">Mudar</a> // Pagando o id da linha
```

update.php

```
  <?php
  include"../../../../../clientes/assets/config.php";
  $sql = "UPDATE notificacoes_geral SET status_lido='1' AND id= $id ";
  $resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi bem queres enviar dados via ajax não mais no `submit` de uma `form` mas quando uma ancora fôr clicada.

Nesse caso precisas de mudar os seletores no jQuery. Mudando o `this` para apontar para a `form` e o seletor ao qual juntas o oscultador de evento deve funcionar.

testa assim:

```
jQuery('#<?php echo $id?>').on('click', function(){
    var dados = jQuery('#ajax_form').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function( data )
        {
            alert( data );
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Nota: usei no seletor o mesmo PHP que gerava o ID da ancora que queres `<a href="#" id="<?php echo $id?>">Mudar</a>`. Porém não sei como é o teu PHP e caso isso não seja fácil, usa um seletor com outras referências ao DOM para encontrar esse elemento `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Fábio.
Bom, tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas pequenas alterações que acredito serem um pouco melhor.

No código abaixo, deixei a tag `<a>` fora do form, mas você poderá deixá-la dentro sem problemas.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").delegate(".btnUpdate", "click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault() //Para anular o comportamento padrão do link
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dados = $("#ajax_form").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dados,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                alert(data)
                                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert(jqXHR)
                                console.log(jqXHR);
            }

        });

    })

});


</script>

<?php $id = 1; ?>

<form id="ajax_form">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?=$id?>" />
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
</form>

<a href="#" id="<?php echo $id?>" class="btnUpdate">Mudar</a>
```

Note que criei a classe .btnUpdate, e ao clicar no link com essa classe, eu recupero o valor do id através da função .attr(). Porém note também que acrescentei um campo hidden no form para receber o valor de id, assim eu consigo serializar o id junto com os demais campos do form.

Você só precisa definir como tratará o retorno do processamento de update.php.
Basta substituir o alert(data) e console.log() pela sua regra de negócio.

OBS: Setei o $id na mão apenas para fins de exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado!